# For $\triangle ABC$ with inradius $r$, if $\frac{c + a}{b} +\frac{c + b}{a} = \frac{c}{r}$, then which angle is $90^\circ$?

Tags: trigonometry

> For $\triangle ABC$ with inradius $r$, if 
>   $$\frac{c + a}{b} +\frac{c + b}{a} = \frac{c}{r}$$ then which angle is $90^\circ$?

My try : [image]

I am stuck here I think my process is wrong please help me in this.

Comment: What is $r{}{}$?

Comment: What exactly are you solving *for*?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire, The inradius maybe.

Comment: For finding which angle among A , B , C is 90° and yes r stands for inradius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality on the $3^{rd}$ line can be written as:

$$r = \frac{abc}{a^2+b^2+(a+b)c}$$

The symmetry in $\,a,b\,$ suggests that the right angle is $\,C\,$, in which case $\,a^2+b^2=c^2\,$, then:

$$\require{cancel}
r = \frac{abc}{c^2+(a+b)c} = \frac{ab\cancel{c}}{(a+b+c)\cancel{c}} =\frac{ab}{a+b+c} = \frac{\cancel{2}S}{\cancel{2}p} = \dfrac{S}{p} \tag{1}
$$

In any triangle the [inradius $\,r = \dfrac{S}{p}\,$](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Inradius) where $\,S\,$ is the area and $\,p = \dfrac{a+b+c}{2}\,$ is the semi-perimeter. For a right triangle $S = \dfrac{1}{2}ab\,$, so $(1)$ holds true, therefore the right angle is indeed $\,C\,$.

Comment: I appreciate your effort but is there any other way to solve it instead of this. Just asking?

Comment: @user580093 This looks to me to be the most direct way to answer the question as posted. That said, there could certainly be `other ways` to answer it, of course.